# Named range array not working or not possible?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a list of options that exceed the 256 chars limit for data validation, so im trying to use a named range from the string array but it does not seem to work or is not possible?

heres the code im trying:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="mylist", RefersTo:="={""one"",""two""}"

With Target.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=mylist"
End With
```

the list is generated from an external database query in vba, i have just show a simple example above.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that data validation only works with ranges...

Comment: Put the list into a hidden sheet. Neither a validation list nor a named range is a good place to store data.

Comment: You get that the named range is **myList** and the data validation uses **myData** ?

Comment: Data validation can use either a range, or a comma separated string as the source for a list. An array will not work. (nor will a defined name referring to a delimited string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you create a named range called **Test** using **Sheet1.Range(A1:A10)** & import a data validation with range values in cell **Sheet1.Range("B1")**

```
Option Explicit


Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook

        .Names.Add Name:="rngTEst", RefersToR1C1:=.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") 'Create the range

        With .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""rngTest"")"
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```